# Set dynamically combobox values on Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a combobox value dynamically from a query with the following code and it's displayed only when I click on the combobox column, if I don't click the value disappears and it's not set.

The first 5 values are related to the user and the one displayed on the combobox might be not set into database, so it might be null if it doesn't exist or Type "A" or "C".

This is image is before clicking on the cell 
[image]

This image is after clicking the cell with data loaded
[image]

This image is after the cell is unclicked and selected any other cell

[image]

```
//This code is used to Build combobox column  after the data is binded 
var items = new[] { new Logica.Items { valor = "C", texto = "Creador" }, new Logica.Items { valor = "A", texto = "Aprobador" } };
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cell.DataSource = items;
cell.ValueMember = "valor";
cell.DisplayMember = "texto";

this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, cell);
this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "TipoUsuario";

for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    string valor = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();//get the first datagridview value
    if (valor != null || valor != "")
    {
        string orgv = string.Empty + this.dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString().ToUpper();//required to fill combobox conditions
        string veg = string.Empty + this.dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString().ToUpper();//required to fill combobox conditions
        string aprobador = string.Empty + this.dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString().ToUpper();//required to fill combobox conditions
        DataTable ds = cargarnodos("LLenaTipoUsuario"); // this query into db to get the combobox values if this exists, if not then it's null.
        foreach (DataRow datar in ds.Rows)
        {
            if (orgv == datar["VKORG"].ToString() && veg == datar["VTWEG"].ToString() && aprobador == datar["idAprobador"].ToString())
            {
                string seleccion = datar["TipoUsuario"].ToString().ToUpper();
                this.dataGridView1[5, i].Value = seleccion; // this changes value


                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[5, 0].Value.ToString());


                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the rows to display the data in the cell even if the row is selected or not. This was done by setting the `DataPropertyName` of the ComboBoxColumn.

```
        cell.DataPropertyName = "valor"; //
```

This should be data column should be available in corresponding to the `Datasource` of the parent `DataGridView` and their data types are identical..

Further if this column in the can contain `null`, you add the following line (if you are allowing the user to select/change etc)

```
        cell.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "-- Select -- ";
```

Comment: cell.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "-- Select -- "; worked fine to set an entry text for the user but cant load the dynamic combobox yet.

Comment: Well, at my end the `DataGridView` was displaying the text entry on the combo. Probably it'd be worth to check if you have customized any of the `DataGridView` properties which causes this as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while loading the form is not possible to set the combobox values. After the datagridview is binded, it's needed to use the following command to edit values based on previous selections.

dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(selecciongv_DataBindingComplete); // selecciongv is the method to do the same proccess.